# Showing a div depending on the userdata

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript and i'm learning in a stranger way let's say but I'd need some help if you all could.

I have found about this
 `if (_userdata.session_logged_in != 0) return;`

which basically means that if you are not 0 (guest) won't do anything for you. My question is, since as i mentioned i am quite new to javascript how can i make it in case it's 1 to display a div and the other way another div.

Not much since I'm not able to understand some things right now and im working on it

Comment: you can use a class to hide the element, lets say in your css you have a class called `d-none` what this does is `display: none !important;` so all those divs are `d-none` by default and you have to remove that class depending on your condition so if your `_userdata.session_logged_in` is `1` then remove the class from the div you wish to show like this `element.classList.remove('d-none')`

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can get the element with the "document.getElementById" (or [Document: querySelectorAll() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and then add a custom class or the style as you prefer.

```js
let user = {
    type: 0,
}
        
if (user.type == 0) {
  let div = document.getElementById('div-hidden');
  div.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-hidden">You can't see this div</div>
<div>You can see this div</div>
```